# recreational maths venue for amateur mathematicians

Tags: journals

does anyone know of a recreational maths venue which publishes, announces, or distributes mathematical results (at university level) which would be of interest to amateur mathematicians also ?

Thank you.

Comment: The newsletter of the European Methematical Society usually has a problem section. Some of this problems can be of interest to amateur mathematicians, too. See
http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/journal.php?jrn=news

Comment: In Europe there is the Recreational Mathematics Colloquium. Its 3rd edition was last month in Açores Portugal. I believe at least the second edition has proceedings you can find.

Comment: The MSRI's Emissary http://www.msri.org/web/msri/pages/16
has a problem section which sometimes includes items with
a recreational flavor.  (And this question should probably be
Community Wiki.)

Comment: @Paslig: Have you ever heard of the Journal of recreational mathematics? If my memory serves me well, one of the first papers on the theme of Ruth-Aaron pairs was published there... 


Comment: Thank you Francesco, Fernando, Noam, J. H. S.
i am happy to see all the suggestions! :)


Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recreational Mathematics Colloquium mentioned in the comments above : http://ludicum.org/ev/rm/13

A mixed bag of (possibly) relevant journals, some of them well-known:

- [Convergence](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/46/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=3334&bodyId=3703)
- [Forum Geometricorum](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/)
- [Mathematical Intelligencer](http://link.springer.com/journal/volumesAndIssues/283)
- Mathematics Magazine: 
  [MAA](http://www.maa.org/pubs/mathmag.html) 
  [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/journals/0025570x.html)
- [Plus](http://plus.maths.org/)

**EDIT**

And more, including a French one:

- [The Mathematical Gazette](http://www.jstor.org/action/showPublication?journalCode=mathgaze) (UK).
- [l'Ouvert](http://irem.u-strasbg.fr/php/index.php?frame=.%2Fpubli%2Fouvert%2Fsommaire.php&m0=online&m1=ouvert&) (not sure about its current status, the site appears not uptodate and somewhat broken)

Comment: yes, these are what i am after! if you have more of this kind, let me know! :) i am also interested in french ones

Comment: American Mathematical Monthly?

Comment: @Paslig: You may also want to take a look at the pages of: 1. The College Mathematics Journal 2. The Fibonacci Quarterly

Comment: Yes, seconding José Hdz. Stgo., _The College Mathematics Journal_ has an annual puzzles and games issue each September and publishes some recreational mathematics in other issues as well.

Answer (score 7):

The Best I know is G4G (Gathering for Gardner Foundation: http://gathering4gardner.org). From 2010, people around the world celebrate the birthday of Gardner and G4G somehow links all of them together. It is up to you at what level you celebrate it. We did it at our own university and students from all departments (science including mathematics, physics, chemistry, and social science) were involved. Just visit G4G and you get many useful ideas and you may share your own ideas.

Comment: Thank you. it certainly draws my attention to things i was not aware of.

Comment: G4G has published several books of proceedings from their conferences. I don't know whether they plan to continue to do this. If they do, that would be another venue for publication.

Answer (score 1):

Also two journals to mention here :

- The graduate journal of mathematics (The Graduate Journal of Mathematics is an electronic journal that publishes original work as well as expository work of general mathematical interest which add to the literature, have pedagogical value and help make more widely accessible significant mathematical ideas, constructions or theorems).
- Journal des élèves de l'ENS Lyon, (original work, expository work and recreational maths, but I don't know their current policy about people not studying at the ENS Lyon and wanting to submit there).