# Are there journals for "fun mathematics"?

Tags: soft-question, journals, recreational-mathematics

Are there peer-reviewed journals that focus on "fun mathematics"?

By this I mean fun things that do involve nontrivial mathematics and which I think other mathematicians would enjoy reading in their leisure time but that are not interesting from the point of view of contemporary mathematical research.

For instance say that I have found a winning strategy for a folklore game that it is not as complicated as chess or Go but also not so trivial that you would figure it out in one afternoon. Or maybe say that I found some nice mathematical "magic trick" that was not known before. Where could I submit these things?

Of course there are journals that just accept more or less anything but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: This usually goes under the name "recreational mathematics." I think a journal like the American Mathematical Monthly is willing to publish articles like this. But possibly there are also whole journals dedicated to recreational mathematics.

Comment: Some journals related to recreational mathematics are mentioned in the answers here: [Recreational mathematics: where to search?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/152580)

Comment: Obligatory "all mathematics is fun!"   (I know, I know, you did carefully define your terms ….)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this usually goes under the name "recreational mathematics."  I'd suggest looking at The Mathematical Gazette as well, which has a range of articles including short notes and problems.